# Request coarse device location returns default value

Tags: actions-on-google

I am developing an action on google for a google home device.

When requesting coarse or precise device location, I receive back (i assume) a default value. I have a location set in the google home app for the device under more settings. The location is outside the US. I tried setting to an address in the US but still get back the same default value for location. Directly asking the device "ok google, where am i", it correctly returns the address that i have set (in and outside the US) as does asking "ok google, what is the weather".

This is the value i get back for device_precise_location:

```
"device": {
    "location": {
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 37.422,
            "longitude": -122.084
        },
        "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
        "zip_code": "94043",
        "city": "Mountain View"
    }
}
```

I am using the sample name psychic project to test getting the location. https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-name-psychic-nodejs

Has anyone been able to request location access and from a google home device outside the US (with the address also set outside the US) and receive the correct address back?

Comment: What's your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: Can you post details about how you are requesting access to the information and then how you're requesting/getting access?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the web-based simulator is always located in Mountain View. The Google Home I use for testing is sending the US location I have been setting (not in Mountain View), and also the users on an action I'm working on come from various cities within the US.

Officially Google Home is US-only, I've seen some users from Mexico with bogus/different zip_code fields which may have been a bug at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing it on Google assistant mobile app or on actual Google Home. Web-based Simulator does send Mountain view coordinates by default.